# Dirichlet function involved with integral

Tags: measure-theory, integration

Let the Dirichlet function $D:[0,\pi] \rightarrow R$ be given by

$D(x):=\begin{cases} 0 &\text{if } x\in [0,\pi] \cap Q,  \\{}\\ 1 &\text{ otherwise}.\end{cases}$

For the function $f(x):=\max \{\sin(x),D(x)\}$ find $\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)dm(x)$

I'm complete lost and confused on how to go about solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose $dm$ inside the integral means you need to integrate with respect to Lebesgue measure. First note that $f$ really is integrable since it is a positive function. Now, $m([0,\pi]\cap \mathbb{Q})=0$ since the set you measure is a countable one. Therefore, if one defines $I:=[0,\pi]\setminus ([0,\pi]\cap\mathbb{Q})$, the integral turns to $$\int_{I}f(x)dm(x)=\int_{I}1dm(x),$$
where the last equality holds since $sin(x)\leq 1$ on $I$. But the RHS there is just $m(I)$ which is the measure of $[0,\pi]$ minus the measure of the countable set $[0,\pi]\cap \mathbb{Q}$ (both $[0,\pi]$ and $[0,\pi]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ are Lebesgue measurable of course). Therefore, $m(I)=m([0,\pi])=\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int f=\int_Qf+\int_{[0,\pi]\setminus Q}f=\int_{[0,\pi]\setminus Q}f$$

Answer (score -1):

Well the first thing you need to tackle is if this function is truly a function.  Does it have points of discontinuity?  Where at?  At those points of discontinuity, you're going to have to break the integral up into separate integrals.

Comment: following as what you said, the function will be discontinuous at all the rational points. Then what follows?